# DatasetGenerationError: An error occurred while generating the dataset

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, databricks, huggingface-datasets, document-layout-analysis

Im trying to load my Publaynet dataset from s3 bucket to data bricks using huggingface datasets like this:

```
dataset_id = "/dbfs/mnt/ocr/dataset/publaynet"
dataset = load_dataset(dataset_id, data_files={"train": "/dbfs/mnt/ocr/dataset/publaynet/train.json", "validation": "/dbfs/mnt/ocr/dataset/publaynet/val.json"}, split="train", cache_dir="./cache")
```

My S3 bucket is in formal like below screenshot:

[image]

Im getting this error in databricks:

[image]